# wcf, DataContract stopped showing

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, c#-4.0

I got a wcf service reference in my client with some datacontracts,
I dont know what i did , but all of a sudden all of the datacontracts are not known,
I got something like 100 Errors when building the project so updating service references or delete and add does not work..

what can i do to fix this ? (i'm using .net 4.0)

Thanks.

Comment: Try posting a few errors' messages here. Also try fixing those errors, it's likely if you fix one or two this will help with all those 100.

Comment: Nothing impotent to show..
i.e , service reference contains classes : class1,class2
My client use this classes via the service reference.
The errors is 

Error 2 The type or namespace name 'class1' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Check that the client side **has** reference to the service (or to the assembly with class1, class2). If this is in one VS solution, check that client project has a reference to the service project. Make sure you can build a service project first - so the physical bin assembly is available. If it is not, fix the error in the Service project and rebuild the whole thing. Does it help?

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your Service Reference [as shown in this MSDN article.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628652.aspx) You most likely clobbered your automatically generated service proxy code and it just needs to be recreated.